# Configure appveyor for Docker

Tags: docker, appveyor

We are using appveyor for Continuous deployment for all of our (.NET) Applications.

Now we are running our applications in Docker.

I am trying to configure appveyor for docker.

Haven't found any proper documenation.

**Is there any sample appveyor.yml file for docker.**

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is to use `Visual Studio 2017` image which is based on Windows Server 2016 and has Docker installed. Minimal `appveyor.yml` would be:

```
image: Visual Studio 2017

build_script:
- docker images  # or your own docker command goes here

test: off
```